# Identifying color ranges

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, colors

For a project I need to go through all the pixels of an image and identify color ranges.  Right now, I've written code that will go through all the pixels and construct an ArrayList of colors for each pixel.  Now, I need to figure out a way to go through my ArrayList and identify groupings of colors.  For clarification, in all pictures there are really only 3 different "colors".  Obviously due to varying brightness across the picture the pixels don't exactly match the RGB values of the 3 different colors.  Thus, I need to find a way to identify a range of variation for each of the 3 different colors.  My theory is to "construct" a graph of the colors in the ArrayList and identify the color ranges by looking for gaps between color groupings.  I'm just not sure how to go about doing this.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Without knowing more about the problem, I can only say that what you're faced with is a [very well-researched](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) area.

Comment: But given that you're trying to group similar colours, you should probably abandon RGB and use the HSV colour space: if it really is only brightness the colours in a group differ in, you can probably group them very easily just by looking at the hue.